# Debian CGROUP Install doesn't work after reboot

Tags: linux, systemd, cgroups, quota

After I do this on my Debian Stretch:

```
sudo apt install cgroup-bin cgroup-tools cgroupfs-mount libcgroup1
```

I can issue this:

```
sudo systemctl set-property user-1000.slice CPUQuota=40%
```

I have 4 vCPU host, each CPU takes 10% hit with "stress -cpu 4", but after reboot, I can no longer get the "CPUQuota" to work, again.

I have already have `"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"`

So how do I get systemd resource management to work after each reboot without having to reissue:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install cgroup-bin cgroup-tools cgroupfs-mount libcgroup1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fixed the problem. (For some reason, after cgroupfs-mount is installed, the file */lib/systemd/system/cgroupfs-mount.service* is linked to */dev/null*.)

```
sudo apt --reinstall instll cgroupfs-mount
sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/cgroupfs-mount.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now created systemd service file:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/cgroupfs-mount.service

[Unit]
Description=CGroups FS Mount

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cgroupfs-mount start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/cgroupfs-mount stop
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Once the file is created, issue:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Check on the status and enable startup during boot:

```
sudo systemctl status cgroupfs-mount
sudo systemctl enable cgroupfs-mount
```

Now test:

```
sudo systemctl set-property user-1000.slice CPUQuota=40%
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```